# I am trying to send form data to pdf and attach with mail

Tags: php, fpdf, html-to-pdf

I am using the below code and it's working. However the attached code does not work, and sending mail failed. Could it be to do with the wrong header?

Here the `$htmlTable` variable is used for collecting form post value and coverting it to pdf using the html to pdf function.
But the mail is not sent with pdf.

```
$pdf->WriteHTML2("<br><br><br>$htmlTable");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
//Create PDF file with data
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$pdf1 = $htmlTable;

 $file = $semi_rand . ".pdf"; 
 $handle = fopen($file, 'w+');
 fwrite($handle, $pdf);   
 fclose($handle);
 // Additional headers
   $subject = "User Form";
    $content = chunk_split(file_get_contents($file));
       $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));  //unique identifier

       //standard mail headers
       $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
       $header .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email']. "\r\n";
       $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";


       //declare multiple kinds of email (plain text + attch)
       $header .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
       $header .="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

       //plain txt part

      //$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
     // $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
     // $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: bit\r\n\r\n";
      //$header .= 'sample'. "\r\n\r\n";


       //attch part
       $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$file."\"\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file."\"\r\n\r\n";
       $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";  //chucked up 64 encoded attch
        $success = mail($to,$subject,'PFA',$header);
       if (!$success) {
      echo "Mail to " . $to . " failed .";
       }else {
      echo "Success : Mail was send to " . $to ;
      print_r ($header);
       }
```

Comment: You tagged this question with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), but you're not using it. You should, then you don't need to worry about how to build attachments properly. Generally, solve one problem at a time - check your PDF build is working before trying to send it. Also, look at `file_put_contents`, it's much simpler than faffing with `fopen`.

Comment: Yes my pdf build is working but i am getting problem in to sending attachment with mail...

Comment: How can the "attached code" be working and the "code below" not working?

Comment: And if it were working it would be vulnerable to email injection.

Comment: I am saying that the form data is converted in to PDF but I have not find the solution how to send pdf buffered data to mail

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class as it's simpler to attach a file and send it by email.

An example of sending an email with attachment can be:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Attachment is here';
$mail->Body    = 'Here goes the attachment;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

I've slightly modified the example which can be found in the link I've shared above.

As **Synchro** suggested you can use `addStringAttachment` method, in order to skip the whole writing the PDF to a file step and send it directly from memory.

Comment: If you make use of PHPMailer's `addStringAttachment` method, you can skip the whole writing the PDF to a file step and send it directly from memory.